# Can I use 'out of' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, phrases

> He left the band **out of** his own decision.

I'm trying to say that It was his own decision to leave the band.
Is this ok to say?

Comment: I'm trying to say that It was his own decision to leave the band.

Comment: Your comment is actually a better way to say this. Alternatively:  _Leaving the band was his own decision_. _He left the band, which was his own decision._ _He left the band of his own volition._ So the simple answer to your question is NO. ;)

Comment: Your sentence is totally fine, grammatically, but it just means he didn't let the band be part of his decision. It doesn't mean that the decision was leaving the band. (*To be left out* would be a phrasal verb here, so "leave" doesn't actually mean "to leave.")

Comment: @JoeDark Volition sounds so super weird and formal or is it just me?  I've never heard that before.

Comment: Your sample sentence can be interpreted in several ways: he made a decision to depart from the band, or he made a decision affecting the band and didn't consider the other members' input.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of **out of** is something more specific than "his own decision". It must be a *motive*.

> He left the band out of jealousy.
>
> He left the band out of boredom.
>
> He left the band out of a desire to strike out on his own.

He left the band of his own volition.  He was not kicked out.

Comment: He left the band out of his own volition. :P

Answer (score 0):

*Out* is not needed:

> He left the band of his own decision.

Comment: What does "of" mean in this sentence ? What are its synonyms?

Comment: In learning a foreign language I was once advised to stop trying to "translate" prepositions and rather just learn where they're used and I've found this advice generally pretty helpful... prepositions do weird things, and the idea of synonyms for them usually doesn't work. In this context, "of" links something to its cause. It's the same way we use it in "I would die **of** shock," or "she did it **of** her own free will." If it helps you to remember you can think of it as a shortening of "He left the band [because] of his own decision" but I'm not certain it actually *is*.

Comment: The easiest way for me to remember what 'of' does is to recall that 'of' is possessive. So 'of' his own decision is the only right preposition. In German, though, we put the word 'out' in front of 'of'  to emphasize that it was his own decision. I see why it is ambiguous in English in this sentence.